# Get integer number using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, integer, latex

I am trying to **write a regex to get only integer numbers** e.g, 23, 234, 45, etc, and not select numbers with decimal points.

***For Context :***

I need it in a larger regex that I am writing to convert mixed fraction latex input
    For example:

```
5\frac{7}{8}
```

But it should not select latex such as:

```
3.5\frac{7}{8}
```

The regex That I have so far is:

```
(^(.*)(?!(\.))(.*))\\frac{([^{}]+(?:{(?:[^{}]+)}|))}{([^{}]+(?:{(?:[^{}]+)}|))}
```

But it is for integer and decimal numbers alike. Need to change the regex for group1.

Comment: Quick answer: Change the start to `(^(\d*)(?!\.\d)...`.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes it does ;) - see this https://regex101.com/r/iINpRm/1

Comment: Improved(?): https://regex101.com/r/iINpRm/2

Comment: Please have a look here [https://regexr.com/3r6ic](https://regexr.com/3r6ic) It is showing no matches

Comment: What is wrong with `^\d+\\frac.*`?

Comment: Your regexr example doesn't have the \ before `fraq`.

Comment: @revo True. Didn't look at it from a birds eye perspective ;). Just the OP original RE.

Comment: it does. it has \\.

Comment: In the regex - yes.

Comment: It appears to be a regexr problem - I added the \ to a fork and it looked OK, but this is what it saved: https://regexr.com/3r6ja

Comment: the tests didn't contain \frac but only frac. Thanks

Comment: But the last case is not matching

Comment: Need a solution without the beginning match as it would not would if the matched text is not present in the beginning.

Comment: Okay then try this [`(?:^| )(\d+\\frac(?:{[^{}]*})+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qcXoYg/1)

Comment: Or, just modifying the start, [`(?:^|[^\d.])\d+\\frac{([^{}]+(?:{(?:[^{}]+)}|))}{([^{}]+(?:{(?:[^{}]+)}|))}`](https://regex101.com/r/D40F0I/1).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do it for you:

```
(?<!\d\.)\b(\d+)\\frac{([^{}]+(?:{(?:[^{}]+)}|))}{([^{}]+(?:{(?:[^{}]+)}|))}
```

It captures an integer expression before `\fraq`, unless it's preceded by a digit and a full stop.

```
(?<!\d\.) This ensures the number isn't preceded by a digit followed by a full stop, i.e.
          the integer part of a floating.
\b        Must be at the start of a number (to make sure we don't get a match with the end
          of a multi digit number).
(\d+)     Captures the integer number
\\frac    Matches the string "\fraq"
```

The rest is the same as you original expression.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iINpRm/6).

**Edit**

Since there obviously are people out there, however unbelievable, that still haven't moved to a real browser ;) - the answer has to change to:

**It depends of the syntax of latex, whether you can do it or not.**
(And since I don't know that, I shouldn't have said anything in the first place ;)

The problem is that, without look behinds, you can't do it without matching characters outside the expression your interested in. In your regexr-example you clearly show that you want to be able to match expression not only at the beginning of strings, but also in the middle of the. Thus we need to be able to tell that the part before our match isn't the integer part of a decimal number. Now, doing this with matching isn't a problem. E.g.

```
(?:^|[^\d.])(\d+)\\frac{...
```

like Wiktor suggested in comments, will match if the expression is on the start of the line (`^`), **or** is preceded by something that isn't a decimal point or a digit (`[^\d.]`). That should do it. ([Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iINpRm/7).)

Well, as pointed out earlier, it depends on the syntax of latex. If two expressions can be directly adjacent, without any operators or *stuff* between them, you can't (as far as I can tell) do it with JS regex. Consider `1\fraq{0}{1}2\fraq{2}{3}` (which I have no idea if it's syntactically correct). The first expression `1\fraq{0}{1}` is a piece of a cake. But after that has been matched, we'd need to match a character before the second expression to verify the it doesn't start with a decimal number, but since the first expression already *ate* the characters, we can't. Because the test `(?:^|[^\d.])` to verify that our expression doesn't start with a decimal number, would match one of the characters that actually belongs to our expression (the `2` in `2\fraq{2}{3}`), thus making the match fail, because the remaining part doesn't start with the digit needed to satisfy the rest of the regex `(\d+)\\frac{...`.

If, however, an expression always starts the string tested, or is preceded by and operator, or such, then it should be possible using

```
(?:^|[^\d.])(\d+)\\frac{([^{}]+(?:{(?:[^{}]+)})?)}{([^{}]+(?:{(?:[^{}]+)})?)}
```

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iINpRm/8).

(Sorry for my rambling)

Comment: The negative lookbehind operator of RegEx is supported only in the recent Chrome version. It is not supported in any other browsers. Can it be done in any other way without using negative lookbehind operator?

Comment: @gvgramazio Justified down (and up) votes is a (necessary?) part of SO to improve quality of, and rate, answers. But they are **so** much more useful if they indicate the reason for the down vote, because then the answerer has the chance to correct/improve the answer (IMO).

Comment: I agree. In fact I tried to suggest the reason, don't know if the real one but surely a possible one.